# ASP.NET updatepanel : updatemode conditional malfunction

Tags: asp.net

I've got a weird problem:

On a page, i've 2 updatepanels in conditional updatemode, with childrenastrigger set to true (default value).

A click on a IPostBackEventHandler control inside either the first or second updatepanel causes the 2 updatepanels to refresh.

This is not the expected behavior. Any Idea?

Comment: Does one of your `UpdatePanels` contain the other?

Comment: Check "How UpdatePanel Controls are Refreshed" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx . See if your setup falls under any of the conditions mentioned in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying,

As often, it finally was a parameter problem:

A team worker had forgot to set the [AssociatedUpdatePanelID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.associatedupdatepanelid.aspx) property of an other updatepanel.
So it seems like this updatepanel was refreshing too.

Moreover, i forgot that on a asyncpostback, all the controls in the page were recreated (even those inside an updatepanel), but not rendered.

It can be disturbing when debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Verify that both update panels don't have `<Triggers>` set for the same control. If they do, then yes, both will update when the control posts back.

Edit: I noticed my original post stripped the `<  >`!

ALSO, verify that in your server-side code, you are not manually triggering an update() on both panels, or even a refresh on the original page.