# UpdatePanel Conditional updatemode not working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510139/asp-net-updatepanel-updatemode-conditional-malfunction) while trying to resolve my issue unfortunately this I can't seem to figure out the problem since I already have everything the way it should be.

I've got 3 updatepanels that each call a function on a .js file setup like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlGeneralinfo" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Sys.Application.add_load(BindPageLoad); 
        </script>
```

Each have a different ID of course. Whenever a control calls a postback within the update panel it works, however in the js file I added a console.log("running the js file") and I can see that it's being called three times meaning it's all three updatepanels are being refreshed instead of just the one.

All the triggers are inside each of the respective updatepanels so I shouldn't need to add any triggers (I did just to make sure and it makes no difference). Shouldn't the UpdateMode=Conditional resolve this?

Also worthy to mention, none of my code behind ever calls any updatepanel.update(). I tried adding that for each control to their respective panels and that also made no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily mean all your update panels are being refreshed.

The MSDN docs say the client load events are raised after either a synchronous (full page postback) or asynchronous (partial page) postback.

This might mean that only one of your update panels is refreshing as intended, but all three event handlers are run again after the async postback because of how they were hooked up using MS Ajax.

**MSDN excerpt:**

> **Client Events of the Application and PageRequestManager Classes**
> **Sys.Application.load Event**
>
> - Sys.Application.add_load(handler);
>
> Raised after all scripts have been
> loaded and all objects in the
> application that are created by using
> $create are initialized. The load
> event is raised for all postbacks to
> the server, which includes
> asynchronous postbacks.
> -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx

**Working with Partial-Page Rendering Events** states a different event that runs only when  the entire page loads:

> During ordinary page processing in the
> browser, the window.onload DOM event
> is raised when the page first loads
> -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976.aspx

This the regular DOM load method, not part of MS Ajax.

Therefore I assume if you hook your client code to the regular **window.onload** event then it will run only when the full page loads, on the first time, not on successive async postbacks (aka update panel/partial refresh).

Whether or not this knowledge is harnessable to provide the outcome you want I'm unsure.  Maybe you're looking at only the MS Ajax objects for a solution when a hybrid browser/MS Ajax client solution exists.